# Starting the same form more than once

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have a project, with a form containing a Panel, called Panel1.

There are no classes, or anything in the form as all the code is held in my control library.

I can start up a single instance of the form with one of my 4 User Controls, however I am looking to have each controls start up in different windows, using the same Form, with the panel.

I have played with the program.cs to allow this, but each form needs to close before opening the next.

Has anyone got any ideas?

THis is not a duplicate of the question cited. As I am attempting to open 1 form, but with different instances of a usercontrol, co currently.

Comment: Which one of these four forms should be main form of your application? Or you aleready have main form (some other form)?

Comment: please post the code that you have been playing with in your program.cs file.  Right now everything is just a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i run two form simultaneously

```
 static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var thread = new Thread(ThreadStart);
        // allow UI with ApartmentState.STA though [STAThread] above should give that to you
        thread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start(); 
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }
    private static void ThreadStart()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2()); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `form.Show()` instead of `form.ShowDialog()` to open form more than once without need to close it.

Comment: There's no `Show` or `ShowDialog` for the main form, it's started with `Application.Run(new Form1());`

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault what main form you are talking about? NOTE: there is `Show` and `ShowDialog` on every form

Comment: He wants to start his application with 4 times the same form (but with different user control inside). And of course adding more Application.Runs (I guess that's what "played with program.cs" means)to duplicate it does not work, as it waits for the current form to close.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault not sure. He didn't say about starting application

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault "but each form needs to close before opening the next." means he uses `ShowDialog`. Otherwise application would exit

Comment: He only have 1 form, and tried fiddling with program.cs. That means at application startup.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault please, read carefully my previous comment

Comment: Try stacking up a few Application.Run in program.cs, you'll see each one needs to close before opening the next.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault try calling form.ShowDialog() several times in program.cs - you'll see each one needs to close before openeing the next. We can only guess what OP tries and wants to do. I'll wait for his reply

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You said he *was* using `ShowDialog`.  Pierre is (I think?) simply saying that he could be doing that, or he could be using `Run`.  Both are options.

Comment: I have tried both of those options, and they both result in the same issue. Even when I declare 

`var test = new form1();`
`test.panel1.control.add(Mycontrol);`
`test.showdialog()` or even `Application.run(newForm1());`

Both result in the same issue, 1 form needs to close before the other.